# C++ fstream confusion

Tags: c++, save, loading, fstream

I have a program that, multiple times throughout, uses fstream to save to files. It works perfectly when running in microsoft vs, but when I compile a release, and bring the .exe to my desktop, it won't write to any files there.

```
ofstream save;
save.open("Data\\options.scav");
/*Write stuff to file*/
```

This works fine in visual studio, but if I bring it to my desktop, and even create the Data folder for it, it doesn't write. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you remove Data\\ ?

Comment: @AngusComber yes, it does.

Comment: Then you know the reason. Create the Data folder if it does not already exist.

Comment: @AngusComber yep I guess I do, thanks, fixed it. If you post as an answer I'll star it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write to a path that has not already been created.

Do like this:

```
// check Data folder exists
ofstream save;
save.open("Data\\options.scav");
```

Note that for portability reasons you can also do this (on Windows or Unix):

```
// check Data folder exists
ofstream save;
save.open("Data/options.scav");
```